# Sending photo via telegram's bot api

Tags: python, api, telegram

I am using telegram bot api (python) and trying to send photo via link, but getting an error:

```
def model(bot, update):
   pic = 'http://pi.lmcdn.ru/img600x866/T/O/TO263AMZGP37_5925451_1_v2.jpg'
   bot.send_photo(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, photo = pic)
```

and I get this error

```
"Wrong file identifier/http url specified"
```

Has anyone ever encountered such a problem? The link is okay, but it can't be sent as photo. Btw this works well with another links.

Answer (score 0):

I got this! The documentation says

> **Sending by URL**
>
> > Other configurations may work but we can't guarantee that they will.

as it was said by other user: "you should send your photos using file_id or multipart/form-data."

Comment: which document? can you provide a linK?